# “Unrecognized selector sent to instance” swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I keep getting a “Unrecognized selector sent to instance” in the `addButtonDidTouch` function when ever I press the button. I have no idea what I might be doing wrong.

```
@IBAction func addButtonDidTouch(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Grocery Item",
                                  message: "Add an item to the list",
                                  preferredStyle: .alert)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
                                   style: .default) { action in
       guard let textField = alert.textFields?.first,
        let text = textField.text else { return }

        let listItem = ListItem(name: text, addedByUser: self.user.email, completed: false)

        let listItemRef = self.ref.child(text.lowercased())

        listItemRef.setValue(listItem.toAnyObject())
    }
```

the whole error im getting is

> [UITableViewController addButtonDidTouch:]: unrecognized selector sent
>   to instance 0x7fba30612ce0

Comment: Make sure that you have added the right outlet in your Storyboard.

Comment: Show the whole message of the error, this could help debugging, knowing which class of elements/method called.

Comment: Is it possible that you changed the name of he method after creating the outlet? The outlet connection won't automatically update in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard you have not set the class of this UITableViewController subclass. In IB, select the view controller, then visit the third tab over in the inspector. You need to set the Class to be your class.

I can tell because the error refers to `UITableViewController` not your custom subclass.

Answer (score -1):

If you have crash with external framework, Add -Objc in Targets -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags